# Delete lines from a file which does not have a key present in another file

Tags: bash, shell

I've a `fileA` which contains multiple lines in the form:

```
clientId=OW&instructionId=cvv-prod&objectId=abc-123&state=WaitForDecision&workId=123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000
```

I've another `fileB` which contains a list of valid objectId's I'm interested in:

```
abc-123
xyz-456
```

Is there a way for me to keep only lines in fileA for which the objectId exists in `fileB` ?
If this was in Java, what I would do is get the list of all objectIds in a Set, and then in `fileA` go line by line, extract the objectId and check if it existed in the set. Wondering if this can be done via a bash script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With different approach with `awk` by making `objectId=` OR `&` as field separators for `fileA` considering that your Input_files will be same as shown samples only.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next} ($4 in a)' fileB FS="objectId=|&" fileA
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** Using match.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  a[$0]
  next
}
match($0,/objectId=[a-zA-Z]+-[0-9]+/){
  var=substr($0,RSTART+9,RLENGTH-9)
}
var in a
'  fileB fileA
```

Comment: @user1692342, could you please do let me know if this helped you?

Comment: solution worked and is much faster than than using grep. I verified only using 1st solution

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `grep` command that does it:

```
grep -Ef <(sed 's/^/(^|\&)objectId=/; s/$/(\&|$)/' fileB) fileA
```

```
clientId=OW&instructionId=cvv-prod&objectId=abc-123&state=WaitForDecision&workId=123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000
```

Note that `sed 's/^/(^|\&)objectId=/; s/$/(\&|$)/' fileB` is used in process substitution to produce a string checking regex for each line of `fileB` as this:

```
(^|&)objectId=abc-123(&|$)
(^|&)objectId=xyz-456(&|$)
```